# Verifying that the function satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\Omega \subset \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by: $f(z)= e^{-z^{-4}}$ if $z \neq 0$ and $f(z)=0$ if $z=0$.

Although not holomorphic at  $0$, does this function satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations in $0$ ?

I'm trying to calculate the limit

$$\lim_{t \to0}\frac{f(t)-f(0)}{0}= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^{-t^{-4}}}{t}= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1}{te^{\frac{1}{t^4}}}$$

If this limit does not exist, is it sufficient to say that it does not satisfy Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: But the limit exists and is $0$.

Comment: Correct and choosing $t_n=\frac{1}{n}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}, -t_n^{-4}=n^4$, shows that indeed the limit doesn't exist

Comment: @Conrad i am calculating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ then t is real, I think Giuseppe is right.

Comment: It seems to satisfy the cauchy riemann equation for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, Right?

Comment: $f$ is not real differentiable at zero as there is no directional derivative at $45°$ so it's weird to talk about differential operators at zero

Comment: Wow, I'm confused. I just saw an exercise in a PDF asking to show that it satisfies the cauchy riemann equation in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Wikipedia definitely claims this function satisfies the CR equations everywhere but is not continuous and cites a 1923 paper by Looman (which I am unable to read). [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Goursat.27s_theorem_and_its_generalizations). This is standard counterexample to show that satisfying the CR Equations is not enough by itself; see the Looman-Menchof Theorem

Comment: I'm trying to do the math, in $ 0 $ it's easy to check, outside of $ 0 $ the calculations are discouraging.